# Where I can find (L)Ubuntu on tablet?

Tags: lubuntu, tablet

everybody.

So, I have Asus Pad tf700t (Infinity). And I want to install Ubuntu(or Lubuntu) on it. With Lubuntu I haven't found any guides of installing.  If you know some, please provide a link to me. Also all links that I have found for downloading Ubuntu Touch are dead, and I have absolutely no idea, where I can find files for installing.

EDIT:  Asus Pad tf700t - tablet with Android OS, so, as I think, installing Linux distr. should be different from installing on desktop or laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You should try downloading the ISO disk image from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu
, under the *Standard PC* section, and then the **PC 64 disk standard image disk option**.
Then, get a usb stick, plug it into your computer, then, using the **Universal USB Installer**, which can be found at http://www.pendrivelinux.com/
, select the distribution in the Universal USB installer program, select the downloaded ISO file, the USB stick(which should be large enough to hold the distribution), and transfer the ISO to the USB. 
Once the program says everything is done, eject the USB stick from the computer and plug it into your tablet computer. Power on the tablet computer, access the boot menu, and boot off of the USB stick. The rest should be easy, just follow the instructions.

NOTE: If you are planning on doing a dual boot, be careful about how you partition(divide) your disk space. You may not be able to change it later. If you are not going to be storing games or pictures on your Lubuntu partition, then you should make that partition smaller than the windows partition, since Linux generally takes up less space than Windows.

Comment: Probably, you've lost that I asked about tablet, not laptop/PC. I think, that I need to have special version. I have used [this tutorial](http://www.themobimag.com/how-to-install-linux-ubuntu-os-on-transformer-pad-infinity-tf700/), but links for downloading are dead.

Comment: Sorry about this late response,  but in my experience, ubuntu desktop will work with a touchscreen right out of the box. I haven't used Lubuntu before, but I suspect the case may be the same with that OS. If your tablet computer can take it, I recommend just getting Ubuntu.